# Django reference url in views.py

Tags: python, django

In Django, I have setup urls.py like the following:

```
url(r'^example/$',   ExampleView.as_view(), name='example'),
url(r'^example2/$',   AnotherView.as_view(), name='example2'),
```

Where "example2" would be like: 'http://localenv.com/example2'.

In my views.py, I'd like to return a reference to the "example2" link. Let me explain:

```
class ExampleView(TemplateView):
    some_var = REFERENCE TO EXAMPLE 2 URL
    print some_var
```

I'd like it that print statement to return "http://localenv.com/example2"

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse).

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class ExampleView(TemplateView):
    some_var = reverse('example2')
    print some_var
```

EDIT:

If you want the absolute uri, you can build it with [`build_absolute_uri`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri)

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class ExampleView(TemplateView):
    some_var = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('example2'))
    print some_var
```

Comment: The import path is now `from django.urls import reverse`

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [urlresolvers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/urlresolvers/). But it will give only  **URI** , you will have to manually add "http://localenv.com...".